# How do I pass a stored value as the column number parameter to edit in awk?

Tags: bash, awk, parameter-passing, sh

I have a .dat file with `|` separator and I want to change the value of the column which is defined by a number passed as argument and stored in a var. My code is

```
awk -v var="$value" -F'|' '{ FS = OFS = "|" } $1=="$id" {$"\{$var}"=8}1'   
myfile.dat > tmp && mv tmp myfiletemp.dat
```

This changes the whole line to 8, obviously doesn't work. I was wondering what is the right way to write this part

```
{$"\{$var}"=8}1
```

For example, if I want to change the fourth column to 8 and I have `value=4`, how do I get `{$4=8}`?

Comment: To change the first column (1 is passed in as a variable): `echo foo bar baz | awk '{$v=k}1' k=qux v=1`

Comment: v takes a value from a stored var, v="$var", and when i use this method the whole line changes to 1

Comment: Whatever you've been using to try to learn awk from, throw it away and get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as you are currently extremely confused about awk syntax and semantics.

Comment: i gogle things, i didnt study no books about awk, forgive me. i found the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer is mostly correct, but just wanted to add a couple of notes, in case it wasn't totally clear.

1. Referring to a variable with a `$` in front of it turns it in to a reference to the column. So `i=3; print $i; print i` will print the third column and then the number 3.
2. Putting all your variables in the command line will avoid any problems with trying to include `bash` variables inside your single-quoted `awk` code, which won't work.
3. You can let `awk` do the output to the specific file instead of relying on bash to redirect output and move files.
4. The `-F` option on the command line specifies `FS` for you, so no need to redeclare it in your code.

Here's how I would do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
column=4
value=8
id=1
awk -v col="$column" -v val="$value" -v id="$id" -F"|" '
    BEGIN {OFS="|"}
    {$1==id && $col=val; print > "myfiletemp.dat"}
' myfile.dat
```

Comment: beware that this is not idiomatic `awk`.  Unless you have a strong reason (filename depends on fields, you split file, etc) you don't print to filename in the script. `awk` encourages condition{action} blocks, should have been written `... $1==id{$col=val}1'.  There is no point of setting OFS at each loop, either set with `-v OFS` or in `BEGIN` block.

Comment: @karakfa thanks I'd meant to make that first code block a `BEGIN` (that's why it was a separate block!)

Answer (score 2):

you can refer to the awk variable directly by it's name, slight rewrite of your script with correct reference to column number var...

```
awk -F'|' -v var="$value" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1=="$id"{$var=8}1'
```

should work as long as $value is a number.  If `id` is another bash variable, pass it the same way as an awk variable

```
awk -F'|' -v var="$value" -v id="$id" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1==id{$var=8}1'
```

Comment: Bash variable `$id` will not get interpreted inside single quotes.

Comment: in the OP $id doesn't seem to be a variable.  I assumed it's a literal.

Comment: that is how you do it, yes. i tried before i saw your reply and worked so that's that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you use a number in a variable by putting a `$` in front of it, you can also use put a `$` in front of an expression!

```
$ date | tee /dev/stderr | awk '{print $(2+2)}'
Mon Aug  3 12:47:39 CDT 2020
12:47:39
```